# What is the longest Weyl element of $SO(2n+1)$?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, weyl-group

Let $w_{2n+2}$ is the matrix with ones on the non-principal diagonal and zeros elsewhere.
Let $V$ be the $2n+2$-dimensional quadratic space with the symmetric bilinear form $\left<,\right>$ given by $w_{2n+2}$.

Let $\{e_1,e_2,\cdots,e_{n+1},e_{-n-1},\cdots,e_{-2},e_{-1}\}$ be the corresponding standard basis of $V$ such that $\left<e_{i},e_{-j} \right>=\delta_{ij}$ and $\left<e_{i},e_{j} \right>=0$.

Let $G$ be the special orthogonal group of $W_{2n+2}$, that is,  $G=SO(W_{2n+2})$ and let $G'$ be the  subgroup of $G$ fixing $e_{n+1}-e_{-n-1}$.

I know that the longest Weyl element of $G$ is $w_{2n+2}$. But I don't know what is the longest Weyl element $w_0'$ of $G'$.

Would you describe the shape of $w_o'$ as a $(2n+2) \times (2n+2)$- matrix?

Thank you very much!

Comment: This question is somewhat confusing to me. The Weyl group is not contained in G so I wouldn't describe either $w_{2n+2}$ or $w'_0$ as $(2n+2) \times (2n+2)$ matrices. As a side note that is not an orthonormal basis you have chosen but a null one: $\langle e_i,e_i \rangle= 0$

Comment: Agreed with @Callum. The Weyl group should be some subquotient of $G$, and although in some cases there are sort of canonical representatives for its elements up in $G$, I am not sure if this is one of these cases. Also, not sure how helpful that is, but the longest element in the Weyl group of the corresponding root system $B_n$ is just multiplication with $-1$, i.e. $w_0 = -id$. (Whereas the negative identity is not even contained in $SO(odd)$, so we certainly cannot represent it in the group like that.)

Comment: It's been a while since I worked out details like this. IIRC on the side of algebraic groups this choice of the symmetric bilinear form (one with maximal Witt index) is used to arrive at the situations familiar from $SL_{n+1}$: 1) triangular matrices form a Borel subgroup and 2) the diagonal matrices form a maximal torus. I don't think I ever bothered finding out, how the land lies on the Lie group side. Is the description $W=N_G(T)/T$ still available? $SU(2)$, sure but even $SO(3,\Bbb{R})$?

Comment: Anyway, when you need a matrix that, by conjugation, turns upper triangular matrices into lower triangular, you need something, where the action is on the non-principal diagonal.

Comment: @Callum, Thank you for a kind reply. You are right! A Weyl element should be that of subquotient of $G$. But if we fix Borel subgorup $B$ and its maximal torus $T$, then we can choose $w_{2n+2}$ in $G$ such that $Bw_{2n+2}B$ should be big cell.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, thank you veru much for such a kind reply. I am wondering what is the big cell $Bw_0B$ in $G$.